# dispalying error returned by stored procedure in .aspx form

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

i have a stored procedure which i use to insert values in a table...if i implement error handling in it using @@ERROR and if i it returns error in a variable @myError can i display this error in my .aspx form??i m using sql server 2005

thanx....

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`InfoMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage.aspx) event of the `SqlConnection` to output SQL warnings and information messages to the client. By default the event is only fired for information messages with a [severity of less than 10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937483%28SQL.80%29.aspx). By setting the [`FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.fireinfomessageeventonusererrors.aspx) property of the `SqlConnection` to true you can trigger the `InfoMessage` event for errors of severity 11 to 16 instead of throwing an exception and halting execution. By adding an event handler for the `InfoMessage` event we can output the message to the client.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();
    conn.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;
    conn.InfoMessage += delegate(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        txtMessage.Text += e.Message;
    };
    ...
}
```

See: [HOW TO: Return Errors and Warnings from a SQL Server Stored Procedure in ADO.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321903)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but normally you don't want to display system error messages to users - it would be better to display a user friendly message instead.

That being said however, just create a label and set the label's `Text` property with the value of `@myError`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using TRY/CATCH in T-SQL instead of @@ERROR. The later is notoriously problematic because is reset after each statement. For more details see

- [Error Handling in SQL Server – a Background](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html)
- [Implementing Error Handling with Stored Procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-II.html)

I much prefer TRY/CATCH, using a procedure template like the one described here: [Exception handling and nested transactions](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/). This way an error is raised into your ASP.Net as a SqlException which you can catch, like any other CLR exception.